# Azure Functions - How to Connect to other services using API connections

Tags: python, azure, sharepoint, azure-functions

I'm new to azure functions, I want to deploy my python code in function app, where my code is linked with SharePoint, Outlook, SQL Server, could some one suggest me the best way to connect all 3 of them in azure functions App....#python #sql #sharepoint #azure

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by connecting 'all 3 of them'? It helps others to give you right information or directions if you describe your use case.

Comment: I would like to link my code to all the above 3, but now I'm able to connect to Sharepoint and SQL server from Functions, to send email from functions, I'm using send grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, would like to discuss about accessing SharePoint files from Azure function, we just need to use few imports for it from VSCode and we also have the python documentation for Office365-Rest-Client.

Below is one of the examples to download a file from SharePoint:

```
Import os
import tempfile


from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from tests import test_team_site_url, test_client_credentials


ctx = ClientContext(test_team_site_url).with_credentials(test_client_credentials)
# file_url = '/sites/team/Shared Documents/big_buck_bunny.mp4'
file_url = "/sites/team/Shared Documents/report #123.csv"
download_path = os.path.join(tempfile.mkdtemp(), os.path.basename(file_url))
with open(download_path, "wb") as local_file:
    file = ctx.web.get_file_by_server_relative_path(file_url).download(local_file).execute_query()
print("[Ok] file has been downloaded into: {0}".format(download_path))
```

To get all the details of files folders and their operations refer to this [GIT link](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/tree/master/examples/sharepoint)

For connecting to SQL we have a [blog](https://www.lieben.nu/liebensraum/2020/06/using-azure-function-msi-to-connect-to-azure-sql-in-python/) which has all insights with Python code, thanks to lieben.

Comment: Your Blog helped me to get the data from sharepoint. Thank you so much